# CSS3 border-radius renders differently in Visual Studio project than in HTML file

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css

I encountered an odd problem when migrating an HTML page I'd been developing in notepad++ over to an ASP.NET MVC web template. The issue is this: I have a table with rounded corners at the top and bottom. It looked fine when I opened the local file on my computer. However, when I placed the HTML page, along with the CSS, into my .cshtml file in my ASP.NET MVC project and rendered the page through visual studio I got this (colors changed for greater clarity):

[image: CSS3 Border Radius - round background, square border]

You see on the top-left, that the dark gray border is not round as it should be (and as it is when I open the normal HTML version of the page in the same browser as shown below.) **Note that the CSS and HTML are the same in both cases, which means this is not simply an issue of "missapplied" style sheets. The CSS should--and does--work, just not when I open the website in Visual Studio. Why is this happening?**

[image: CSS3 Border Radius - normal version]

(Also note that I'm actually changing the style of the top-cell-one-to-the-right of the actual top-left cell, but that isn't the issue since the same thing happens on all the other corners.)

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
/*top left corner*/
table tr:first-child td:first-child + td {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

/*bottom left corner*/
table tr:last-child td:first-child + td {
    border-left: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
}

/*top right corner*/
table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-right: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

/*bottom right corner*/
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-right: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who offers a possible solution!

Comment: Which doctype are you using? Have you compared the source of the rendered page with your original html version? There may be some characters before the doctype that are throwing the browser into quirks mode.

Comment: @GWB, I hadn't thought of trying that. Turns out that wasn't the issue, but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. If anyone else runs into this issue and finds this question, the issue is with the normalize.css file included automatically in the standard visual studio template. Inside that file, the border-collapse property was set to "collapse" for the table tag. When I disabled this, the issue disappeared. So the moral of the story--or at least one moral of the story--is that if you are applying a border radius to a table cell with a border, make sure that "border-collapse" is **not** set to "collapse", otherwise the border will not be rounded. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the top-left and top-right border radius on the table itself, or whichever element has the grey border.

```
table {
 border:3px solid #ddd;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/*top left corner*/
table tr:first-child td:first-child + td {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

/*bottom left corner*/
table tr:last-child td:first-child + td {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
}

/*top right corner*/
table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

/*bottom right corner*/
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: The same element has the grey border. That's what's so strange. As you can see, it looks fine when I open the HTML file in my browser (see second screenshot). I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Get rid of the individual grey borders around each the the tds and just add the grey border to the table then.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect changes.

Comment: I can't do that because I'm not actually applying the style to the top left of the table. If you look at my question, I'm applying it to second cell in the top row. Also, note that the CSS I have works when I open the HTML file, so the issue isn't simply that I'm applying the style the wrong way. The issue only arises when I open the project in visual studio.

Comment: Are you using the WYSIWYG in Visual studio to view this design? I'm sure being a MS product latest being 2010, that the renderer doesn't support CSS3 propertys.

Comment: No I'm running the project in Chrome, the same browser that I opened the HTML file in.

Comment: I'm just confused since I do a lot of .NET Front-end integration and have yet to run into this problem. It doesn't make sense that opening it from your desktop and opening/running it in VS make a difference in your css rendering.

Comment: Also, if you look carefully, you'll notice that the border radius of the green box in the picture renders fine in both cases.

Comment: I know... it's strange. I don't know why it would make a difference either. Literally everything else is the same both ways I render it.